# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError instead of MainMethodNotFound

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

On executing the below class, "**Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**" is thrown. I expected the exception to be thrown as "**MainMethodNotFoundException**".

Why noClassDefFoundError was thrown here?

```
public class TestingSwitch {
    public static void main(String args) {
        int cnt = 1;
        switch(cnt){
            default: 
                System.out.println("Welcome");
            case 1:
                System.out.println("One");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Two");
                break;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: How are you executing this code? Can you tell us the command you're using to execute java?

Comment: Guys
I am pretty sure that the main method signature is wrong.
But the answer I'm looking forward is:  why "NoClassDefFoundError" instead of MainMethodNotFound?

Comment: Yes, I see. But it depends on the command you're using to execute the class. Are you sure the class you're typing in the console exists and is compiled?

Comment: Yeah the class file had been generated. 
Used javac<filename.java> for compilation. and java <filename.class> for exceution.

Other Specs:
JDK Used: 6

Comment: Don't use java xxxx.class.   remove .class, use java xxxx

Comment: Same exception: NoClassDefFoundError --> even executing by "java xxx"

Answer (score 1):

Wrong method signature.

Change:

```
public static void main(String args)
```

To:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: `java.lang` is always included

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `public static void main(String args)` this to `public static void main(String[] args)`

run this

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int cnt = 1;
            switch(cnt){
                default:
                    System.out.println("Welcome");
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("One");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Two");
                    break;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error :

```
public static void main(String args)
```

You have to write

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it gave me a different error.

These are the steps I've tried:

1. Create a class `TestingSwitch`

   ```
   vi TestingSwitch.java
   ```
2. Put there your content

   ```
   $ cat TestingSwitch.java 
   public class TestingSwitch {
      public static void main(String args) {
         int cnt = 1;
         switch(cnt){
            default: 
               System.out.println("Welcome");
            case 1:
               System.out.println("One");
               break;
            case 2:
               System.out.println("Two");
               break;
         }
      }
   }
   ```
3. Compile the class

   ```
   javac TestingSwitch.java
   ```
4. Now there are two files in the directory

   ```
   -rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  xxxx   518 Oct 26 11:33 TestingSwitch.class
   -rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  xxxx   373 Oct 26 11:33 TestingSwitch.java
   ```
5. Try to execute the class:

   ```
   $ java TestingSwitch
   Error: Main method not found in class TestingSwitch, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
   ```

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8:

```
  java version "1.8.0_31"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
```

Comment: Yeah I too tried in Java 8....... It thrown Main method not found i.e same as yours